# Rscript and Incredibuild

Tags: rscript

I have a simple function f1(paramter) in a "functions.txt" file.

I write a batch file test.bat as follows

```
FOR /L %%G in (-100,1,100) do xgSubmit.exe /group=tt1Test /command  Rscript.exe -e 
"source('functions.txt');f1(%%G)" > "Out.%%G.txt"
```

In the windows command prompt I use

```
xgConsole.exe test.bat /openmonitor /AvoidLocal=ON
```

What I am trying to do is compute function f1() in different machines using incredibuild.

What I observe is the function that are running locally returns a value in files 
 Out.%%G.txt but the functions running remotely fails with the following error

```
Error in structure(.Internal(Sys.getenv(as.character(x), as.character(unset))),  : 
 unsupported conversion to 'UCS-2LE' from codepage 1252
Calls: local ... eval -> eval -> as.vector -> Sys.getenv -> structure
Execution halted.
```

The remote machines do not have R program installed.

Am I doing the correct thing ? 
Should incredibuild and Rscipt be able to work even though R program is not installed in the remote computer ?

It would be very kind to provide a detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a Unicode problem in the remote machines.
Many Unicode problems have been fixed since this question was submitted.
I assume your bug is already fixed in the latest version of IncrediBuild.